# Does the Google Drive Activity API work for Team Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I could not find a clear answer on the API reference for the [Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/) as to if it will also work with Team Drives. I want to be sure that this is possible for Team Drives before I spend all that time trying to integrate it into my application.

Specifically, I would like to check when a file was moved to a certain folder, and it seems like this is the API I need to use.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is available in Activity API but I've something related. Try using [Reports API: Drive Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive#retrieve_drive_name_events_for_team_drives), it does support retrieving Google Drive events for Team Drives. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @Mr.Rebot . I haven't found anything about dealing with specific files in the link you provided. Do you know of any streamlined way to specify that we want activity on a certain file, or do we have to wade through a list of activity for an entire Team Drive or user to find this info?

Comment: @ruby-is-pretty-cool : You can set Alerts from your Admin panel. You can set these alerts on a specific file and on specific activity. Visit [this](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#Reports:subtab=drive-audit) in Admin console.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi Thank you! The link you posted just took me to this page, https://apps.google.com/user/hub, but while looking for what you were talking about I found [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive#retrieve_drive_name_events_for_team_drives), which sounds promising. I'm going to try it out and see what I can do with it.